# How to put changing matrix entry into pie chart

Tags: python, matrix, pie-chart

I wonder how to put active number in pie chart, not fixed number.

They want put Score[:,:1] in pie chart, classified with A(over 90),B(Over 80 below 90),C(Over 70 below 80), D(else). Also, when we get new Score then pie chart need to be changed too.

I tried find the way but only showed to put fixed number.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def main():
    Score = np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 4))
    piechart(Score)
print(main())


def piechart(Score):
    np.where(Score>=90,'A',np.where(Score>=80,'B',np.where(Score>=70,'C','D')))
    arrlist = [len(A),len(B),len(C),len(D)]
    label=['A','B','C','D']
    plt.pie(arrlist,labels=label)
    plt.show()
```